# Can I Manage My Shelter's Power Usage?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Whenever I am low on power the first building to lose power is the kitchen. This is undesirable since food is a very important resource.

**Is there a way to power down other rooms in order to power up others during power shortages?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot manually power down a room.

The rooms power down based on how far away they are from a power source. The farthest rooms lose power first. Place your most important rooms near the power source to ensure that they keep functioning.

Comment: That's right. One common strategy is to build your living quarters on the bottom layers of your vault, farthest away from the power so when you're running low on power, they lose power but you don't loose any production.

Comment: Storage rooms also can be placed in the "basement" No biggie if they lose power for a bit.